# static keyword in android

Tags: java, android

I don't really understand the following `static` block.  I understand the static keyword when using with methods and variable, but I don't know exactly what the purpose of the static key word on the following code.

```java
static
    {
        sURIMatcher.addURI("contacts", "people", PEOPLE);
        sURIMatcher.addURI("contacts", "people/#", PEOPLE_ID);
        sURIMatcher.addURI("contacts", "people/#/phones", PEOPLE_PHONES);
        sURIMatcher.addURI("contacts", "people/#/phones/#", PEOPLE_PHONES_ID);
        sURIMatcher.addURI("contacts", "people/#/contact_methods", PEOPLE_CONTACTMETHODS);
        sURIMatcher.addURI("contacts", "people/#/contact_methods/#", PEOPLE_CONTACTMETHODS_ID);
        sURIMatcher.addURI("contacts", "deleted_people", DELETED_PEOPLE);
        sURIMatcher.addURI("contacts", "phones", PHONES);
        sURIMatcher.addURI("contacts", "phones/filter/*", PHONES_FILTER);
        sURIMatcher.addURI("contacts", "phones/#", PHONES_ID);
        sURIMatcher.addURI("contacts", "contact_methods", CONTACTMETHODS);
        sURIMatcher.addURI("contacts", "contact_methods/#", CONTACTMETHODS_ID);
        sURIMatcher.addURI("call_log", "calls", CALLS);
        sURIMatcher.addURI("call_log", "calls/filter/*", CALLS_FILTER);
        sURIMatcher.addURI("call_log", "calls/#", CALLS_ID);
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is called static initializer block in Java. This will be executed on class load. Red this oracle [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html).

static initializers may be used to initialize the class variables of the class.

Answer (score 5):

From [**Java Language Specification**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.7):

> A static initializer declared in a class is executed when the class is
>   initialized (§12.4.2). Together with any field initializers for class
>   variables (§8.3.2), static initializers may be used to initialize the
>   class variables of the class.

```
StaticInitializer:
     static Block
```